# retrieve marker icon from marker data set

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm making a website using Google Maps API v3.
Markers are added into the map with attributes being taken from marker data

**Marker Data set**

```
var markerData = [
    "lat": '21.0236081',
    "long": '105.789596',
    "icon": 'http://i.imgur.com/0Js6A7w.gif',
    "description": 'blah blah'
];
```

**Pin marker onto map**

```
for (var i = 0; i < markerData.length; i++) {
    var data = markerData[i];
    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.long);
    var image = "'" + data.icon + "'";
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatLng,
        icon: image
    });
    (function (marker, data) {
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
            infoWindow.setContent(data.description);
            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
        });
    })(marker, data);
    markerList.push(marker);
}
```

I couldn't get the link to put into 'icon' attributes of my markers.
Can someone give me some advice?

Thank you all!!

Comment: Did you check `data.icon`?

Comment: But where you passed map object to marker?? It must be passed

Comment: Hi, I have another function to set marker on map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a number of typos in your code:

1. markerData should be an array of Objects, the `lat` and `long` properties should be numbers:

```
var markerData = [{
  "lat": 21.0236081,
  "long": 105.789596,
  "icon": "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png", // 'http://i.imgur.com/0Js6A7w.gif',
  "description": 'blah blah'
}];
```

2. you need to set the `map` property of the markers to your `map` object:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: myLatLng,
  icon: image,
  map: map
});
```

3. you have extra quotes around your icon:

```
var image = "'" + data.icon + "'";
```

should be:

```
var image = data.icon;
```

(`data.icon` is already a string)

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/v5s8z8ow/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var geocoder;
var map;
var markerList = [];

function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  var markerData = [{
    "lat": 21.0236081,
    "long": 105.789596,
    "icon": "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png", // 'http://i.imgur.com/0Js6A7w.gif',
    "description": 'blah blah'
  }];
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  for (var i = 0; i < markerData.length; i++) {
    var data = markerData[i];
    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.long);
    var image = data.icon;
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatLng,
      icon: image,
      map: map
    });
    (function(marker, data) {
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function(e) {
        infoWindow.setContent(data.description);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
      });
    })(marker, data);
    markerList.push(marker);
    bounds.extend(myLatLng);
    if (markerList.length > 1) map.fitBounds(bounds)
    else map.setCenter(myLatLng);
  }
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I figured out the same way by myself.

Answer (score 0):

You must pass map object to marker

```
 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ // put a marker on map
                position: {lat:lat, lng:lng},
                map: map,
                icon: iconURL
    }
```